# SQL Query - hexadecimal vs. decimal values

Tags: sql

I expected to find the answer to this question fairly quickly, but surprisingly, don't seem to see it anywhere.

I'm guessing that a comparison to a binary constant in an SQL query would be faster than a comparison to a decimal number, as the binary constant is probably a direct lookup while decimal numbers need to be converted, but is the performance difference measurable?

In other words, is the first query better than the second one? If so, how much better?

```
select *
from Cats
where Cats_Id = 0x0000000000000086
```

```
select *
from Cats
where Cats_Id = 134
```

Comment: please tag with database platform.   regardless, there would not be any performance difference. Or at a minimum, any difference would be just be "noise" relative to everything else your application is doing

Comment: Both those numbers are actually strings. Both need converting (while parsing the statement, which itself is a string, and prior to building the execution plan). You're labouring under numerous misapprehensions, and engaging in premature optimisation.

Comment: Neither of those are strings, save in the source code. They are numeric literals. One is expressed in base 16, the other in base 10. You can test this because the expression `0x0086 = 134` will evaluate to `true`, while the expression `'0x0086' = '134'` will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: They are strings, as the whole statement is a string. And, as I said, need to be converted during parsing. Then they're binary, never are they some intermediate hex or decimal representation of a binary value.  I'm not suggesting the plan processes them as strings, I'm suggesting Everything he's typed and passes to the parser is a string, so the notion that one is closer to the underlying data's true representation is a fundamental misapprehension.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is yes. **In some cases, the query with the hexadecimal value is substantially better.**

I hired a consultant DBA to help us with our system and after reviewing one of our queries, which was running a bit slow, he showed me that changing the value to hexadecimal improved it substantially (by about 95%).
He then showed me that, although I had an index on the field I was searching (binary foreign key), **the index wasn't used when executing the query with the decimal value**.

If anyone can provide a more detailed answer about the different cases in which these queries are identical or not, performance wise, I would appreciate that.

Comment: This basically feels like a new question, which is maybe the question you thought you were asking in the first place, but not the one that people answered. It doesn't explain _why_ there is a performance difference, but does mention details of the schema and query that were missing in the original question. The question "why does this query not use the index, but this one does", accompanied by a [mcve] or at least schema details, might well get better answers.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. My answer, however lacking in detail, gives a perfectly good answer to the question "are the two queries different", and as far as I'm concerned, is demonstrably more accurate than the other answers given.

Comment: Also, I don't think the schema and query were missing from the OP, or that the question should have been "why does this query not use the index, but this one does" as the question was a general one and is the one I intended to ask. I don't see how it's my fault if people answered a question I didn't ask. Also, as far as I know, there may be additional cases in which the second one is better, and if so, I would like to know that and stick with the OP.

Comment: I stand by my answer, just as you stand by yours. Your question posed a theory about the query always being better, which was wrong. It did not ask "are there any edge cases where this would make a difference in performance, for better or worse?" If you felt that your question had been misinterpreted, you could have left comments at the time; you could have explained what led you to ask the question, provided more context. You still could, or could ask a new question with this new example. I have a theory about why this edge case occurs, but refuse to answer a question posed as an answer.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. The question "is X better than Y" requires no context, no explanation and no comments. In this case, it had a simple answer, which was "yes, in these cases it is, in others, it is not". You are fixating on a minor side issue from my answer, which frankly, feels like it has more to do with your answer of "no, they are the same, and the very question implies ignorance on many levels" being demonstrably false. Regardless, this particular discussion has been going on long enough, so I'll let it lie at that and thank you for the input.

Comment: I guess your question can be read two ways, or perhaps as two parts: one is asking "is there any circumstance when X is better than Y?"; the other is "is my understanding of what will happen here correct?" It's quite clear from all the comments you received at the time that people were focussing on that second aspect, and pointing out flaws in your reasoning; at the time, you seemed to accept this feedback, but now you are saying that this was a misunderstanding of the question all along. That's unsatisfying for you, but it's also unsatisfying for everyone else who answered in good faith.

Answer (score 0):

Your premise is based on a misunderstanding:

> the binary constant is probably a direct lookup while decimal numbers need to be converted

The SQL you enter consists of characters in some text encoding; for simplicity, let's assume ASCII.

In the computer's memory, it's composed of a long string of binary states we normally write as `0` and `1`, but could equally write as `_` and `|`.

The binary data for the string `134` in ASCII looks something like `__||___|__||__||__||_|__`. The binary data for the string `0x0086` looks something like `__||_____||||_____||______||______|||_____||_||_`

When actually working with the data, e.g. comparing numbers, the computer will use a different representation altogether. The number "one hundred and thirty-four" will look something more like `|____||_`.

So whichever representation you use, there is a conversion going on.

Nonetheless, one conversion *might* be more efficient, by some incidental detail of its implementation, but by such a tiny margin that it would be almost impossible to measure amongst the noise of the system you're testing.

Comment: If anything, the length of the string literal representing the hex value will incur an increased overhead during parsing. And still, as you say, it would be impossible to reliably measure.

Comment: @MatBailie That's certainly one factor; but it is possible that the implementation might implement hex-to-bin with some clever fixed-width processing tricks, and so be slower at processing decimal literals. That's why I left it open which might end up faster.

Comment: @MatBailie — Whatever "increase" in parsing time might incur is infinitesimal compared to the amount of time spent computing the execution plan and/or actually executing the query.

Comment: No database I've ever studied parses literals in to anything other than native data types. Integers, for example, don't have hex or decimal variants, they are native binary integers. The notion of an intermediate representation (between the string literal and the native value used by the execution plan) is a red herring.

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not sure what "intermediate representation" you're talking about. Are you seeing something implying there is one in my answer?

Comment: @NicholasCarey As I said, impossible to reliably measure, for the reasons you mention, amoung others. And, as per my comment on the OP, the entire question is based on misapprehensions and premature optimisations.  The question itself is an indication that the OP is mistaken in more ways than I can count, and should discard this thought post haste.

Answer (score 0):

There absolutely no difference: `0x0000000000000086` is an integer with a decimal value of 134. It's just written in base 16 (hexadecimal).

The two queries are exactly identical and will get exactly the same execution plan.

The one different will be if the column you are comparing to is `binary(n)` or `varbinary(n)`. There the hex constant is representing a sequence of octets.